# RxJava - how to stop PublishSubject from publishing even if onNext() is called

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, publishsubject

I have a look in which i am calling the following:

```
// class member
var myPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create<SomeObservable>()
```

```
// later on in the class somewhere:    
while(true){
   myPublishSubject.onNext(someObservable)
}
```

I would like to stop the emission but have the while loop continue forever. So I want the onNext call to do nothing.  But I'm worried that if I call myPublishSubject.onComplete() that eventually the subject will be null and I will get a NPE. Is there anymore just to silence it even if onNext() is repeatedly called. Is the best way just to unsubscribe?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish nor when that `while(true)` thing will ever terminate.

Comment: I'm listening in a zip call. The moment the myobservable changed I'm triggering an action. But after I finish the subscription method I no longer need the subject. I want to end the onnext call but continue the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few notes**

This is a pretty much a rare case, but if you can show us your real intention with the `Observable`, we might help you out architecting it, if not best, better.

**What you can do**

For my examples, I have only used a flag variable which is pretty straightforward, this could be changed on whatever trigger you have for your project.

**Option 1**

You can directly invoke `onComplete` on the subject publisher

```
val maxEmittedItemCount = 10
var currentEmittedItemCount = 0
val someStringValue = "Some observable" // Create whatever observable you have
val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()

publishSubject.subscribe({
    currentEmittedItemCount++
    println(it)
}, {
    println(it)
})

while (currentEmittedItemCount != maxEmittedItemCount) {
    // Print indication that the loop is still running
    println("Still looping")

    // Publish value on the subject
    publishSubject.onNext(someStringValue)

    // Test flag for trigger
    if (currentEmittedItemCount == maxEmittedItemCount) publishSubject.onComplete()
}
```

**Option 2**

You can also hold a reference to the subscription then dispose it afterwards, this is a little bit more semantic than the previous one as it will execute the code block without calling `onNext(t)` when the resource is disposed.

```
lateinit var disposable: Disposable // Will hold reference to the subscription
var maxEmittedItemCount = 10
var currentEmittedItemCount = 0
var someStringValue = "Some observable" // Create whatever observable you have
var publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>()

disposable = publishSubject.subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<String>() {
    override fun onComplete() {
        // Print indication of completion for the subject publisher
        System.out.println("Complete")
    }

    override fun onNext(t: String) {
        // Test flag count synchonizer
        currentEmittedItemCount++

        // Print out current emitted item count
        System.out.println(currentEmittedItemCount)

        // Print current string
        System.out.println(t)
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        // Print error
        System.out.println(e)
    }
})

while (currentEmittedItemCount != maxEmittedItemCount) {
    // Publish value on the subject
    if (!disposable.isDisposed) publishSubject.onNext(someStringValue)

    // Test flag for trigger
    if (currentEmittedItemCount == maxEmittedItemCount) {
        publishSubject.onComplete() // optional if you need to invoke `onComplete()` block on the subject
        disposable.dispose()
    }

    // Print indication that the loop is still running
    System.out.println("Still looping")
}
```

**Read more on**

- https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64
- https://medium.com/@nazarivanchuk/types-of-subjects-in-rxjava-96f3a0c068e4
- http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/Disposable.html

Comment: what i am worried about in your option 1 is that the subject will be null after calling publishSubject.onComplete().  then i will get NPE during the while loop iteration.  Am i wrong ?

Comment: It will never return null, what happens under the hood after you invoked `onComplete()` is that it sets the subscribers' state to `TERMINATED`. Here's the check inside on next when the subscribers are terminated. `if(subscribers.get() == TERMINATED) return`. Basically it tells that it just skips subscribers that are already disposed. One thing to take note, is that you cannot call `onComplete()` and `onError()` together. Choose one, more on: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6181

Answer (score 0):

As the the observer is subscribed we must call unsubscribe to avoid a multi onNext call.

I suggest to call **onComplete** when the work of **subject.onNext()** is done:

here is an example

```
PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

source.onNext(1);
source.onComplete();

source.subscribe(getObserver());
```

And then in the observer, we re-create another **PublishSubject** instance

```
 source.subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(Integer value) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {
                                        source = PublishSubject.create();
                                    }
                                });
```

Hope this approach help you in your request